# Android interface issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create this interface:[image: this]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/displayGenericDialog"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/displayMessageTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMessageTitle"
            android:layout_width="910dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="100sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/displayMessageCenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.58"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMessageText"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="492dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="40sp"
            android:paddingRight="40sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messagePicture"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/image_view_border"
            android:layout_margin="70sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/displayMessageBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.11"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendResponseIB"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/panel_x"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:onClick="closeProtip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leftTextGenericDialog"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#ff72CCCC"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/rightPictureGenericDialog"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/panel_x"
            android:onClick="closeP" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The background is set programmatically because the header color can variate. [image]
First TextView `textMessageTitle` is used for the white title and programmatically is set to size 50 and bold.

The second one `textMessageText` is font size 40. If the displayed message contains just text and no image the text should be centered else it should be left half the text and the right half the image.
I've tried:

```
if(image)
  TextView.setPadding(200, 0, 200, 0);
else
  TextView.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
```

The next TextView `rightTextGenericDialog` is the one with `Send response` text and `sendResponseIB` is an image button on the left of the text. The TextView and the Image button should be alligned in the center, bellow the center line and below those should be the close ImageButton.

The problem is my interface doesn't look like it should.
I'm new in Android programming so please be gentle.

Comment: Did you solve this? Did the answer below work?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not expect this to work for you straight away. I have made some changes to the weights and layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/displayGenericDialog">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/displayMessageTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMessageTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/displayMessageCenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMessageText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="40sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="40sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messagePicture"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_margin="70sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/displayMessageBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendResponseIB"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/panel_x"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="closeProtip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leftTextGenericDialog"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#ff72CCCC"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightPictureGenericDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/panel_x"
        android:onClick="closeP" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this and let me know if this doesn't meet your requirement.